# how to get code value in these textfields using flutter

Tags: flutter

I have a form-style page where users can enter 4 digit code using widget `Ot`. I don't know how i can get the entered codes and submit them, anyone has any idea?

i need to submit the form and get all the 4 digit codes.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
        elevation: 0,
        leading: IconButton(
            onPressed: () {},
            icon: const Icon(Icons.arrow_back_ios_new),
            color: Colors.black),
        actions: [
          IconButton(
              onPressed: () {},
              icon: const Icon(Icons.info),
              color: Colors.black),
        ],
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          const SizedBox(
            height: 40,
          ),
          const Icon(Icons.dialpad_rounded, size: 50),
          const SizedBox(
            height: 40,
          ),
          const Text(
            "Enter Mary's PIN",
            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 40),
          ),
          Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
            children: const [
              Otp(),
              Otp(),
              Otp(),
              Otp(),
            ],
          ),
          const SizedBox(
            height: 40,
          ),
          const Text(
            "Rider can't find a pin",
            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Otp extends StatelessWidget {
  const Otp({
    Key? key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SizedBox(
      width: 50,
      height: 50,
      child: TextFormField(
        keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
        style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline6,
        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
        inputFormatters: [
          LengthLimitingTextInputFormatter(1),
          FilteringTextInputFormatter.digitsOnly
        ],
        onChanged: (value) {
          if (value.length == 1) {
            FocusScope.of(context).nextFocus();
          }
          if (value.isEmpty) {
            FocusScope.of(context).previousFocus();
          }
        },
        decoration: const InputDecoration(
          hintText: ('0'),
        ),
        onSaved: (value) {},
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to provide a callback function to your `Otp` so it provides the value to parent widgets:

```dart
class Otp extends StatelessWidget {
  const Otp({
    Key? key,
    required this.onChanged,
  }) : super(key: key);

  /// Callback used to provide the entered code to parent widgets.
  final ValueSetter<String> onChanged;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        // Your code...
        onChanged: (value) {
          if (value.length == 1) {
            FocusScope.of(context).nextFocus();
          }
          if (value.isEmpty) {
            FocusScope.of(context).previousFocus();
          }
          onChanged(value);
        },
        // Your code...
        onSaved: (value) => onChanged(value ?? ''),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Then in the parent widget you should store the values provided the code-entering widgets, for example using an array:

```dart
class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  final List<String?> _codes = [null, null, null, null];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
          // Your code...
          Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
            children: [
              Otp(
                onChanged: (code) => _codes[0] = code,
              ),
              Otp(
                onChanged: (code) => _codes[1] = code,
              ),
              Otp(
                onChanged: (code) => _codes[2] = code,
              ),
              Otp(
                onChanged: (code) => _codes[3] = code,
              ),
            ],
          ),
          // Your code...
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```